# Azure Storage, price of reading the Tier of a blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

we have the need to be 100% which costs is incurred by doing the following operations on a blobstorage General Purpose V2:

```
// Determine the tier of a given blob:
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
var cloudBlobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var blob = cloudBlobClient
                .GetContainerReference("container")
                .GetBlockBlobReference("image.png");

var blobTier = blob.Properties.StandardBlobTier;
```

Reading the tier of a blob as done above, what type of operations are they classified from a billing perspective;

1. "Read Operations" **or**
2. "All other operations (per 10,000), except Delete which is free"when reading
3. Other?

Microsoft pricing pages: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

Regards Niclas

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be `Read Operations`, as the [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) mentioned:

> The following API calls are considered read operations: **GetBlob** and SetBlobTier (when it moves a Blob from Archive to Cool, Cool to Hot, or Archive to Hot. Learn more).

In the [Get Blob REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) ,

> The `Get Blob` operation reads or downloads a blob from the system, including its metadata and **properties**.

When you using the storage sdk, it may call the `Get Blob` api.